# GBQ SQL: Return blank spaces if a record is not found in the table

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a query as below. I would like SQL to return blank spaces if a key is not found in the table.

Select * from table_A where key in (1, 2, 3, 4)

```
Output:
1   x   y

2   a   b

'' ''  ''

4   ds  c
```

Assuming table_A has 3 columns and key 3 record in not in the table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of empty strings you should work with NULL values to be type-safe.
NULL indicates that there is no value present in contrast to empty string or zeros which are still values of a certain type.
If you wanted to use empty strings you'd have to cast the key to a string on the run - not very convenient.

The trick to get your result is to create an ideal key-table with all keys - I'm using generate_array here from 1 to the max(key). Then left join your table to it and voila:

```
WITH test AS (SELECT * FROM UNNEST([
  STRUCT(1 AS key, 'x' AS col1, 'y' AS col2), 
  STRUCT(2 AS key, 'a' AS col1, 'b' AS col2), 
  STRUCT(4 AS key, 'x' AS col1, 'y' AS col2)
  ])
  )

SELECT 
 test.*
FROM UNNEST(GENERATE_ARRAY(1, (SELECT MAX(key) FROM test))) AS key
LEFT JOIN test USING(key)
```

gives you

[image: result]

If you wanted all keys, just `SELECT * FROM ...`

Comment: Thanks a lot Martin. It worked. But the key values are not in order. I used to different method to generate those keys.

Thanks for the approach!!